# How to define a static ClusterIP in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I know we can set Public-IP as a static if we define LoadBalancer but can we set a static Cluster IP for service?

Example:

```
**NAME                           TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE**
service/my-application-service   ClusterIP  10.111.67.245   <none>        80/TCP     11d
```

Comment: what is the use case of doing it?

Comment: I am setting a dns aliases for 1 pod because of keycloak (sso) application and if one day the Ip of service changes, dns-alias won't work as expected and thats why I want to define a static IP for service and set a dns alias for this IP

Comment: I made a research already but could not find anything on google

Comment: Have you looked at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname

Comment: Kubernetes provides its own DNS: `my-application-service` is a valid hostname, pointing at the Service's internal IP address.  You shouldn't need to replicate this behavior in your application setup.

Answer (score 14):

It looks like you can specify the clusterIP field under spec on a ClusterIP kind service.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myawesomeservice
  namespace: myawesomenamespace
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.43.11.51
  ...
```

Most relevant snippet from docs

"If an address is specified manually, is in-range (as per system configuration), and is not in use, it will be allocated to the service; otherwise creation of the service will fail" - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/services-resources/service-v1/

And here is the full paragraph.

> **spec**
>
> **clusterIP (string)**
>
> clusterIP is the IP address of the service and is usually assigned
> randomly. If an address is specified manually, is in-range (as per
> system configuration), and is not in use, it will be allocated to the
> service; otherwise creation of the service will fail. This field may
> not be changed through updates unless the type field is also being
> changed to ExternalName (which requires this field to be blank) or the
> type field is being changed from ExternalName (in which case this
> field may optionally be specified, as describe above). Valid values
> are "None", empty string (""), or a valid IP address. Setting this to
> "None" makes a "headless service" (no virtual IP), which is useful
> when direct endpoint connections are preferred and proxying is not
> required. Only applies to types ClusterIP, NodePort, and LoadBalancer.
> If this field is specified when creating a Service of type
> ExternalName, creation will fail. This field will be wiped when
> updating a Service to type ExternalName. More info:
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies

src: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/services-resources/service-v1/